# Game server turn timer

Tags: java, sockets, timer, multiplayer

I'm making a Java multi-player turn-based game and I want to limit the time that each player have to make their move, the game is composed of game sessions or rooms and each room have 4 players.
The game have around 40 game sessions and each sessions have a minimum of 160 turns.

First I looked into the `java.util.Timer`, then I found out about the `ScheduledExecutorService` which seems much better, I could have a `SingleThreadScheduledExecutor` for each game session, create a new runnable each turn and if the player make is move before the runnable is executed I could call the `ScheduledFuture.cancel()` method.

In theory it seems fine but I have some concerns, so I want to know if:

- Is this the right approach? or there are better alternatives?
- Could I just have a `ScheduledThreadPool` for all game sessions instead
  one `SingleThreadScheduledExecutor` for each game session?
- I noticed that canceling a `ScheduledFuture` will keep it in the
  memory until his execution time, could this be a problem for the
  memory usage?
- And last, is it possible to reuse the same runnable (1 for each game
  session) instead of creating a new one each turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ScheduledExecutorService` is a fine place to start.  Just remember to properly synchronize your access to game state.

It is generally legal to recycle a runnable, but that is probably not the best option here.

Unless the number of turns were going to be huge, the overhead for cancelling tasks is not worth it.  Instead, include in your runnable information on what turn in what game is being timed. When the task executes, check the game state to see if that is still the current turn, and do nothing if the turn count has already moved on.

This avoids race conditions between `cancel()` completing and the task executing, as would happen when a move is submitted close to the deadline.

Comment: The number of turns will be around 30.000 per hour. Letting the task execute and only check for the game state seams the easier solution, but memory wise do you think it would be better to cancel the ScheduledFuture, considering the amount of turns?

Comment: each object will be under 20 bytes.  So if the deadline is one hour to move, that's only ~600k for a core feature, which is nothing.  If the deadline were a day, that is still under 15megs, which isn't enough to bother worrying about.  If the deadline is much longer, you probably want to save your deadlines to disk, and periodically scan them in and only schedule those which are for the near future.